# "Variance" estimate for quasi-Monte Carlo

Tags: variance, estimation, quasi-monte-carlo

**Problem Setting**

I am playing with a toy example and I would like to better understand the variance results that I get when using low-discrepancy sequences versus random values. I have independent and identically distributed samples $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}, \, x_i \in\mathcal{X}$, that have a probability mass function $p:\mathcal{X} \to [0,1]$. In fact I first generate uniform values in $[0,1]^D$ and then use a map $f:[0,1]^D\to \mathcal{X}$ that has a density equal to $p$ (i.e. $f$ partitions $[0,1]^D$ in such a way that a region of volume $p(x)$ gets mapped to $x$). This is actually key, as I would later use the same map but on low-discrepancy samples.

**Estimator**

Now for the preliminaries. I build the following estimator:

$$I_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \implies E[I_n] = E[x] = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}xp(x).$$
And I have chosen an example where I know the expectation $I = E[I_n]$.

**Numerical Variance Estimates**

Using that the samples are independent (i.e. $E[\langle x,y\rangle] = \langle E[x],E[y]\rangle$), I can also compute the variance as:
\begin{align}
Var[I_n] &= E[\|I_n-E[I_n]\|^2] \\
         &= E[\|I_n\|^2-2\langle I_n, E[I_n]\rangle +\|E[I_n]\|^2] \\
         &= E[\|I_n\|^2] - \|E[I_n]\|^2 \\
         &= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nE[\|x_k\|^2]-\sum_{k=1}^n\|E[x]\|^2\right) \\
         &+ \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i\ne j}^{n,n}E[\langle x_i, x_j \rangle]-\langle E[x_i], E[x_j]\rangle\right) \\
         &= \frac{1}{n}\left(E[\|x_k\|^2]-\|E[x]\|^2\right)
\end{align}
Now a numerical estimate of this (with Bessel's correction) would look something like:
\begin{equation}
    Var[I_n] \approx \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{n}{(n-1)}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k\|^2}{n} - \frac{n}{n-1}\|I_n\|^2\right) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\|x_k\|^2 - n\|I_n\|^2}{n(n-1)}.
\end{equation}
As an alternative, using the fact that $E[I_n] = I$ is known, I also compute the variance as (I am not sure whether I ought to have Bessel's correction here):
\begin{equation}
    Var[I_n] \approx \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k\|^2}{n} - \|I\|^2\right) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\|x_k\|^2 - n\|I\|^2}{n^2}.
\end{equation}

**Goal**

Ultimately my goal is to use the variance as a proxy for the squared $L_2$ error $\|I_n-I\|^2$ when it is not available. However in this case it is available so I can do some comparisons. I have no issues with the above estimates for random samples as both variances seem to keep close to the $L_2$ error for large enough $n$.

**Low-Discrepancy**

Now I do the same, but this time around I pick the initial points in $[0,1]^D$, that get mapped to $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, according to a low-discrepancy sequence. They still have the same probability mass function in some sense since they inherit that from the map $f$, and they do fill up the space uniformly, so for enough samples this also converges to the expectation. In fact since this is a low-discrepancy sequence the error scales as $O\left(\frac{\log^D N}{N}\right)$ compared to the random case which has a scaling of only $O(n^{-1/2})$. This behaviour is clearly visible when comparing the $L_2$ errors $\|I_n-I\|^2$ of the two approaches. However the variance estimate computed using the low-discrepancy samples exhibits the same behaviour as for the random sequence, i.e. it is not a good predictor of $\|I_n-I\|^2$ for the low-discrepancy case.

**Questions**

Would taking into account the correlation of the low-discrepancy samples (if I could somehow  estimate it) fix this issue, or do I need some other notion to properly approximate $\|I_n-I\|^2$? In fact what would a numerical estimate for the variance be if I had correlated samples (even in the case of random)?